How to integrate Skia with Angular 18 and handle WASM errors in VSCode?
I'm working on a small Angular 18 application in VSCode where I want to use various functions from Skia, including saving content as a PDF. Unfortunately, I'm struggling to create even a simple prototype with canvaskit-wasm.

Installed canvaskit-wasm.
Created a component with the following code:

// draw-skia.component.html
<canvas #canvasElement width="800" height="600"></canvas>

// draw-skia.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import CanvasKitInit from 'canvaskit-wasm/bin/canvaskit';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-draw-skia',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './draw-skia.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./draw-skia.component.scss']
})
export class DrawSkiaComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('canvasElement', { static: true }) canvasElement!: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  async ngOnInit() {
    const CanvasKit = await CanvasKitInit({
      locateFile: (file: string) => `node_modules/canvaskit-wasm/bin/${file}`
    });
    
    // Additional Skia-related code would go here.
  }
}


When I run the application, I get the following error messages:

wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: WebAssembly: Response has unsupported MIME type 'text/html; charset=utf-8' expected 'application/wasm'
canvaskit.js:3400
falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation
canvaskit.js:3401
failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed
canvaskit.js:3391
Aborted(both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed)
canvaskit.js:3355
ERROR
RuntimeError: Aborted(both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed). Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info.

It seems like the WebAssembly (WASM) file isn't being served with the correct MIME type. I'm not sure if this is an issue with Angular's development server or if I'm missing some configuration.
Has anyone worked with Skia in an Angular environment and encountered this issue? Are there any specific configurations or workarounds that I need to implement? Alternatively, can you recommend a good tutorial on integrating Skia with Angular?
Thanks in advance for your help!
